# Handle TimeZone with laravel and eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I wrote an app using laravel and eloquent, all my datetimes are stored with UTC time and my database is using UTC too.. The frontend show the correct timezone to the user but in this moment i have a big problem:

I'am trying to query all the events that will happens today but with the utc timezone many of my events are stored in the next day.. i am in panamá and a event will happen at 20:00 but in utc will start at the next day at 01:20.

how can i query the events that will happen today using carbon and eloquent?

```
    $date  = (!$request->date ? Carbon::today() : Carbon::parse($request->date));
    $matches = Match::whereDate('matches.matchtime', '=', $date)
    ->where('sport','=', $value)
    ->with('results')
    ->get();
```

if the user don't sent a date i use today to get the data.. but this is a problem because when i try to get the today's matches or events i get events that in my timezone happened yesterday.

Comment: Use full timestamps; in pseudo-code, "get events between start timestamp and end timestamp", instead of "get events between start time and end time". The issue with only using times is you end up with cross-overs like this that you can't quite handle. What does the query you're using look like?

Comment: oh sorry @TimLewis, i edit the question.

Comment: let me know if you can help with this query @TimLewis

Comment: Afraid I can't at the moment; might help to add an output of the value of `$date`, and a sample of `$matches`, specifically `$match->matchtime` (if outputted in a loop); might be able to provide additional clarity. Question is in a much better spot of some code though; thanks for adding that.

Answer (score 1):

you can pass a timezone to `Carbon::today()` when you envoke the method so if you want to get "today" relative only to your timezone you would do

```
Carbon::today('America/Panama');
```

And that will get the timestamp for the beginning of the day in Panama.